# string indices must be integers ERROR python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe created this way:

```
dfquery=sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT CONCAT('CAST(', target_column_name, ' AS ',
              CASE 
                WHEN target_column_data_type IN ('NVARCHAR', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR', 'NCHAR') THEN 'STRING'
                WHEN target_column_data_type = 'DECIMAL' THEN concat("DECIMAL", "(",target_column_number_length, ",", target_column_number_precision, ")")
                ELSE target_column_data_type
              END,
              ' )', 
                      CASE 
                WHEN KEYFLAG IS NOT NULL THEN concat(' AS BK_',target_column_name)
                ELSE concat(" AS ", target_column_name)
              END) AS concatenated_string
    
FROM mdp_dev.cfg.schema_
where source_object_name = '${personal.table}'""")
```

this gives me a one column dataframe make a list out of it with this code:

```
mylist = list(
    dfquery.select('concatenated_string').toPandas()['concatenated_string']
)
```

my goal is to loop through this list and create the string, which I attampted to do in the below code:

```
sql_query_test = f"""CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {catalog}.{schema}.`vw_{source}_{table}`
                    AS SELECT
                    """
for c in mylist:
    sql_query_test +="`"+ c["COLUMN_NAME"] + "`,\n"
sql_query = sql_query_test[:-2]
sql_query += f"""\n FROM {catalog}.{schema}.`{source}_{table}`"""
```

but I get the error  point to this

```
sql_query_test +="`"+ c["COLUMN_NAME"] + "`,\n"
```

saying that

> > TypeError: string indices must be integers

Any advice how to fix this?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and post the whole error traceback message, not just the final line.

Comment: The error is telling you that somewhere you are indexing a string with something other than an integer.  Notice that `my list` is filled with strings, therefore in your `for` loop the variable `c` is a string, and then you call `c["COLUMN_NAME"]`

Comment: yeah, sorry I forgot to indicate the the line its. I eddited the post

Comment: @Kurt you are right, error point it there, any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: try replacing that line with `print(c)` and maybe that will make it clear

Comment: @Kurt not really, it prints c

Comment: and what does c contain?

Comment: values from list_of_columns

Comment: share some examples?

Answer (score 0):

`mylist` is a list of string objects so pyhon interpreter is expecting what appears before `c` in `[]` to be a integer rather than `"COLUMN_NAME"`.